# React -- remove dom elements created by an external CDN

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, cdn, react-dom

I am building a portfolio to show work I have created. It includes some small projects from FreeCodeCamp that are built according to test specs. I would like to include the tests so that someone looking at the code can see the tests.

When you embed the cdn script in your index.html file in a react app hosted anywhere, they work fine (even though React doesn't want outside forces manipulating the DOM). This will install a hamburger menu that can be exploded and you can choose which tests you would like to run. **Note that this hamburger is always displayed.**

However, I don't want to always have this hamburger menu because some of what I want to  display is how the page is styled. I am trying to wait and insert the script tag until a button is pressed.

I can successfully display and remove the hamburger menu if I hit the add then remove buttons in order, but I know that I am doing this wrong when it comes to React design. This is obvious by the fact that if you hit add to dom button 2 times in a row, then it won't be removed. Also, I can run the test suite the first time. But if remove the hamburger and add it back and try to run the tests, there are errors in the console.

My question is: **how can you properly add/remove a cdn script element (which will automatically add a dom element (hamburger), in a proper "React" design?** I am thinking that solution lies with useEffect, useRef, or useState, but I am to "green" in React and when I research I still can't design a solution that works.

I put the code in a sandbox. To recreate the problem, just click the show the hamburger button, then hide the hamburger button, then show again and try to run the tests. Or click show several times in a row.

Any tips on how to fix this would be appreciated. This problem way exceeds my little experience.

[Link to Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-tree-dqofx?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out myself. In React, To safely make an element loaded into the DOM via external CDN appear and disappear was as simple as CSS.

I just added the item to the DOM with the CDN script tag. Then I could change either `display:none` or `visibility: hidden`.

The trick was loading the CDN script in first, then hiding it.

I was encountering a problem because I was trying the faulty approach of adding the CDN script tag, and removing, and adding again.